# How do you say "mixtape" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

I've looked it up and haven't really found a good answer (either nothing or I guess it stays "mixtape" with Spanish pronunciation?

I have to write journal entries in Spanish and I'm not sure about this word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not used to the term, but after a little research I think we just say 'mixtape' in English (well, with the English pronunciation we Spaniards have :-D ).

I'm pretty sure you can use the original English term without any problem, since the [Spanish version of wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixtape) and several Spanish journals and media do:

[El Pais](http://cultura.elpais.com/cultura/2012/03/12/actualidad/1331579614_568347.html)

[Vice](http://www.vice.com/es/tag/mixtape)

[El Mundo](http://www.elmundo.es/elmundo/2012/07/31/valencia/1343726209.html)

Be aware they use the femenine for mixtape in Spanish.

Disclaimer: I'm from Spain and have searched in Spanish media, maybe in South America they do have a specific term.

Comment: No es un campo que me ataña, por lo que no sé cómo es de usual el término entre los aficionados, pero «cinta de mezclas» parece no tener mala acogida según Google.

Comment: @guillem de hecho, en la película de Guardianes de la Galaxia, a la cinta "Awesome mix" del protagonista la subtitulan como "mezcla alucinante".